# React how to pass parameter between 2 components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component :

```
    pays11 = iconAllemagne;
    pays12 = iconHungrier;
    score11_12='2 - 2';
    bonus11_12 = 'x0';



    render() {
        return (
            <Page>
                <Heading as="h1" size="lg" color="primary" mb="50px" style={{ textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: '100px' }}>
                    Result match
                </Heading>
                <Hero>
                    {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title */}
                    <Match country1={this.pays11} country2={this.pays12} score={this.score11_12}/>
                </Hero>
            </Page>
        )
    }
}

export default Euro
```

And I want to pass parameter pays11 and pays12 to my Match component :

```
class Match extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Row>
            <img src={this.props.country1} alt='' width='100'/>
            {this.props.score}
            <img src={this.props.country2} alt='' width='100'/>
          </Row>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Match
```

I don't understand why I can not get this data in my Match component ?

Comment: What are the values of `iconAllemagne` and `iconHungrier`? I don't see any over issues with the snippets, but they are incomplete. Is there an error? What is the actual vs expected results? What debugging have you done already?

Comment: @DrewReese Hi ! thank you for your feedback. IconAllemagne and iconHungrier are image variable (the path of the image). I have this error : TS2339: Property 'country1' does not exist on type 'Readonly{}> & Readonly{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Comment: Are you using Typescript? Have you defined PropTypes for `Match`? Seems an odd error for vanilla JSX. Can you update your question to include ***all*** of the `Match` component definition, and all of the parent component code rendering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a functional component
2. Destructure the props
3. Use 'any' as a type to make Typescript happy. Better define a Type though.

```
const Match = ({country1, cointry2, score}: any) => { 
    return (
        <div>
          <Row>
            <img src={country1} alt='' width='100'/>
            {score}
            <img src={country2} alt='' width='100'/>
          </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Match
```